# Merge in postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, postgresql-9.5

Am trying to convert below oracle query to postgres,

```
MERGE INTO table1 g
USING (SELECT distinct g.CDD , d.SGR
from  table2 g, table3 d
where g.IDF = d.IDF) f
ON (g.SGR = f.SGR and g.CDD = f.CDD)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (SGR, CDD)
   VALUES (f.SGR, f.CDD);
```

I made changes as below compatible to postgres:

```
WITH f AS (
SELECT distinct g.CDD , d.SGR
from  table2 g, table3 d
where g.IDF = d.IDF
),
upd AS (
update table1 g 
set 
SGR = f.SGR , CDD = f.CDD 
FROM f where g.SGR = f.SGR  and g.CDD = f.CDD  
returning g.CDD, g.SGR
)
INSERT INTO table1(SGR, CDD ) SELECT f.SGR, f.CDD FROM f;
```

But am doubtful ,my oracle query is not updating any columns if data matched , but am unable to convert it accordingly . Can anyone help me to correct it ?

Comment: Are you getting error messages?

Comment: If you don't want to update the target table, then why do you have an `UPDATE` in your migrated statement?

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you start with a new project today, you should be using Postgres 10, not 9.5 (it's like starting a new project with an outdated Oracle 11 today)

Comment: @JavierLarroulet :: Am not getting any error message , as i have used update table its changing the output values . Update should be removed and implemented same as oracle logic

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : our project requirement is 9.5 . though outdated ,unwillingly we have to use this one .I was unable to convert it without update in migrated code ..Can you suggest how can i convert this oracle to postgres query without updating my table ?

Comment: Remove the CTE with the `update`? But for a more efficient (and free of race-conditions) solution see my answer

Comment: I tried your suggested approach , but i got an error ,ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
SQL state: 42P10 .. Can you suggest on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a primary (or unique) key on `(sgr, cdd)` you can convert this to an `insert ... on conflict` statement:

```
insert into table1 (SGR, CDD)
select  distinct g.CDD, d.SGR
from table2 g
  join table3 d ON g.IDF = d.IDF
on conflict (cdd, sgr) do nothing;
```

---

If you don't have a unique constraint (which bears the question: why?) then a straight-forward INSERT ... SELECT statement should work (which would have worke in Oracle as well).

```
WITH f AS (
   SELECT distinct g.CDD, d.SGR
   from table2 g
     join table3 d on g.IDF = d.IDF
)
INSERT INTO table1 (SGR, CDD) 
SELECT f.SGR, f.CDD 
FROM f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select *
                  from table1 t1
                     join f on (t1.sgr, t1.cdd) = (f.cdd, f.sgrf));
```

Note that this is **NOT** safe for concurrent execution (and neither is Oracle's MERGE statement). You can still wind up with duplicate values in table1 (with regards to the combination of `(sgr,cdd)`).

The only sensible way to prevent duplicates is to create a unique index (or constraint) - which would enable you to use the much more efficient `insert on conflict`. You should **really** consider that if your business rules disallow  duplicates.

---

Note that I converted your ancient, implicit join in the WHERE clause to a modern, explicit `JOIN` operator, but it is not required for this to work.

Comment: Am getting below error : ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
SQL state: 42P10

Comment: Then you don't have a unique constraint on `(cdd, sgr)` - why not?

Comment: Table shouldn't be modified , Is there any other approach apart from this ?

Answer (score 0):

New Postgres version 15 now support merge statement, You don't need to use alternate cte

Here is an example

```
MERGE into b using a on a.id = b.id
when matched then 
  update set x = b.x + 1
when not matched then 
  insert (id,x,status) values (a.id,a.x,a.status);
```