# Conversion of SQL server merge code to equivalent Postgresql code

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, postgresql, migration

How to convert merge of SQL server to equivalent postgresql code:
I am new to SQL Server and not aware how merge behaves

```
merge PortfolioAssetClassBenchmark_Subset as t
 using @inputBenchmark as s
    on t.PortfolioId = @PortfolioId and t.StartDate = s.F_STARTDATE
 when matched and isnull(s.F_BENCHMARK, 0) != 0 and t.AssetClassBenchmarkId != s.F_BENCHMARK then
    update set 
    t.AssetClassBenchmarkId = s.F_BENCHMARK
 when matched and isnull(s.F_BENCHMARK, 0) = 0 then
    delete  
 when not matched by target and isnull(s.F_BENCHMARK, 0) != 0 then
    insert (PortfolioId, StartDate, AssetClassBenchmarkId)
    values (@PortfolioId, s.F_STARTDATE, s.F_BENCHMARK) 
 when not matched by source and @clearExisting != 0 then
    delete
 output  inserted.AssetClassBenchmarkId [InsertedAssetClassBenchmarkId]
    , inserted.StartDate [InsertedStartDate]
    , deleted.AssetClassBenchmarkId [DeletedAssetClassBenchmarkId]
    , deleted.StartDate [DeletedStartDate] 
 into @tmp
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far ?  Please check [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html) [Previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497478/merge-in-postgres)

Comment: I am using Postgresql 12, Merge is no longer supported in this version. The only approach i know as an alternative is Insert on conflict

Comment: @swapnilsolanki . . . Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i just want to know the syntax that i may use to replicate same in postgresql